# How to avoid vulnerability issues in wkhtmltopdf having iframe tags

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

wkhtmltopdf have security issues because of iframe tags.
is there any option to avoid this?

I am using wkhtmltopdf 0.12.5 (with patched QT ) and found that vulnerability issues may occur because of iframe tags.
How to handle this?

Comment: Why not update wkhtmltopdf? Also, why not parse the markup before passing it to the PDF generation?